# Get class name dynamically with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get this class name dynamically in jquery:

```
echo "<div id=\"maini\" class=\"type_" .$category. " start_" .$adSize. " color_" .$color. "\"> \n";
     echo " " . $siteName . " \n";  
echo "</div> \n";
```

as you can see the class name is generated with PHP.

I need the class name for this snippet of code. But what I tried does not work -> $("div." + this.id). :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        maini_s = $("div." + this.id).remove();
        num_of_arts = maini_s.length;
        ipp = 3;
```

Here is the entire js file in case you need to see the other elements before.

```
var maini_s;
var num_of_arts;
var ipp;

function handlePaginationClick(new_page_index, pagination_container) {
    var pc = $(pagination_container);
    pc.children('div#maini').remove();
    for(var i=new_page_index*ipp; i < (new_page_index+1)*ipp ;i++) {
        if (i < num_of_arts) {
                pc.append(maini_s[i]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    maini_s = $("div." + this.id).remove();
    num_of_arts = maini_s.length;
    ipp = 3;


    // First Parameter: number of items
    // Second Parameter: options object
    $("#News-Pagination").pagination(11, {
        items_per_page:ipp, 
        callback:handlePaginationClick
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the classname, just pull the class attribute:

```
var className = $(".element").attr("class");
```

Be sure that you take into consideration that sometimes elements have multiple class names, seperated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but the syntax...

```
"div." + this.id
```

would be looking for DIVs with the class name contained in this.id, not the ID.  If you want to select by ID, I believe you'd want...

```
"div#" + this.id
```

which would use the # ID selector and not the . class selector.

Answer (score 0):

you call `maini_s = $("div." + this.id).remove();` from the `$(document).ready(function()`

The `this` keyword in this case refers to the window.document element .. which normally has no id ..

are you sure you want to run it from there ? or perhaps a click event on some other item ?